# Cannot read property 'hasGlyphForCodePoint' of null react-pdf

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-pdf

I know this happens when I register a new font and create some pdfs on the page.
When the font is standard, the error disappears, but I need Polish characters łść, etc.

This is my simplified code:

MyDocument

```
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet, Font } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

Font.register({
  family: "Roboto",
  src:
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ink/3.1.10/fonts/Roboto/roboto-light-webfont.ttf"
   });

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    fontFamily: "Roboto"
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

const MyDocument = ({number,owner, title, charge, term, account}) => (

    <Document> 
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} >       
        <View style={styles.section}>
           <Text>Tytuł: {title}</Text>
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
)
```

```
import MyDocument from './pdf.jsx';

// (...)
 const FinancesTable = finances.map((finance, index) => {
            const { _id, allotment_number,owner,  title, area, charge, term, status, account } = finance;
            
            return (
                <tr key={_id}>
                    <td>{allotment_number}</td>
                    <td>{title}</td>
                    <td>{area} m²</td>
                    <td>{charge} zł</td>
                    <td>{term}</td>
                    <td>{status}</td>
                    <td>
                        <PDFDownloadLink
                        document={MyDocument({ number: allotment_number,
                                               owner: this.props.auth.user.firstname+ ' '+this.props.auth.user.lastname,
                                               title: title,
                                               charge: charge,
                                               term: term,
                                               account: account,
                                            }) } 
                        fileName="faktura.pdf">
                        {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Ładowanie...' :  <Button style={BlueButtonStyle}>Pobierz</Button>)}
                        </PDFDownloadLink></td>
                </tr>
            );
    // (...)
return <tbody>{FinancesTable}</tbody>
```

Polish characters work for the first item on the arrays, the next one is "Loading ..."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful to someone, I solved it by creating a new component where i passes props and get pdfdownloadbutton and import it to my main component

```
import PdfButton from './PdfButton.jsx';

// (...)
<PdfButton id={_id}/>
// (...)
```

PDFButton.jsx

```
import { PDFDownloadLink } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import MyDocument from './pdf.jsx';

class PdfButton extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            id: this.props.id,
        }
    }
   
    render() {
        const FinancesList = () => {
            const [finances, setFinances] = useState([]);
            useEffect(() => {
                const requestFinancesList = async () => {
                    const financesList = await api.getAllFinances();
                    const { data } = financesList;
                    setFinances(data.data);
                };
                requestFinancesList();
            }, []);

        const FinancesTable = finances.map((finance, index) => {
            const { _id, allotment_number,  title, area, charge, term, account } = finance;
            if(_id === this.state.id){
                return ( <PDFDownloadLink
                key={_id}
                    document={MyDocument({ number: allotment_number,
                                           owner: this.props.auth.user.firstname+ ' '+ this.props.auth.user.lastname,
                                           title: title,
                                           area: area,
                                           charge: charge,
                                           term: term,
                                           account: account,
                                        }) }   
                    fileName="faktura.pdf">
  {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Ładowanie...' :  <Button style={BlueButtonStyle}>Pobierz</Button>)}
</PDFDownloadLink>
        );
                                    }

        })
        return FinancesTable
    }
// (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const registerFont = () => {
    Font.register({
        family: 'Open Sans',
        src: `https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0e.ttf`,
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    registerFont();
}, [])
```

Include these custom fonts (Font.register()) as early as possible. May be in index.js or in App.js ()

If the issue is still there, then render these ReactPdf Elements i.e. PDFDownloadLink
after some timeout

```
const [flag, setflag] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        var timer=setTimeout(() => {
          setflag(true);
        }, 100)
    }, [])

{flag && <PDFDownloadLink document={resumeComponentInst} fileName="somename.pdf">
    {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
        loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!'
    }
</PDFDownloadLink>}
```

This will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call `Font.register` before rendering anything as this will also cause this error. However, from this code snippet it's not clear where rendering happens.